# How to undo iPhone slo-mo on a video?

Tags: iphone, camera

When recording a video in slo-mo in iPhone, it is saved so that the first x seconds are regular speed, then it smoothly transitions to the slow-motion speed, then near x seconds from the end of the video it smoothly transitions back to regular speed.

What method can I use to turn a slow-motion iPhone video sent to me from someone else back into a regular-speed video all the way through?

Simply multiplying the video speed by 4 using regular methods won't cut it because of the regular speed parts at the start and end, and smooth transitions in-between them.

Answer (score 3):

That depends on how the video was sent to you. If the slow motion is "baked-in" to the video you currently have, it will be hard and you will need video editing software to do it.
"Baked in" means instead of the e.g. 120FPS you film a slow motion video at the video is played at 60FPS.
The iPhone automatically plays the first and last part of the video at double the speed and all the rest at normal 60fps.
This is where the slow motion effect comes from.
If you received the Video via WhatsApp or some App that transcodes the video to compress it (so that it does not take up as much data when being sent to you) this app will have baked in the slow motion parts.

Your best option is to ask the person who took the video if they could AirDrop the original file or send it to you via iCloud Link or some App that does not tamper with the video in any way.
This way you will have the video in full quality and you can choose where you want slow motion and where not.